# I want to add the icon in the input field

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYKk8.png)I want to add an icon on the right side input text field

```js
View style={styles.InputContainer}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.input}
              placeholder="EMAIL"
              placeholderTextColor="#0F286A"
              autoCapitalize="none"
            />
            <Icon
              name="ios-person"
              size={25}
              color="#4F8EF7"
              style={styles.inputIcon}
            />
          </View>
```

Comment: here just you need to add proper style pls find link here
https://snack.expo.dev/@aboutreact/-image-inside-textinput-example?session_id=snack-session-5bs1FKKUo

Comment: Hi Thank you for your help but I don't want to use IMAGE I want to use icon only on the right side please check my screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to adapt this to your use case but this is the idea, please note that the container view is the container for the input, not the main container. To add it to the right you just need to switch them around.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
            <FontAwesome
                style={styles.icon}
                name="user"
                size={30}
                color="rgb(0, 200, 160)"
            />
            <TextInput
                style={styles.input}
                placeholder={props.placeholder}
                placeholderTextColor="rgb(150,150,150)"
                onChangeText={(e) => changeHandler(e)}
            />
        </View>
```

Styles:

```
container: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.6)',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        width: '100%',
        padding: 14,
        borderBottomWidth: 2,
        borderRadius: 3,
        marginTop: 15,
    },
    input: {
        color: 'rgb(220, 220, 220)',
        fontSize: 14,
        width: '73%',
        alignSelf: 'center',
    },
    icon: {
        marginRight: 12,
        width: '10%',
        alignSelf: 'flex-start',
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

<TextInput label={Password} right={ <TextInput.Icon color="grey" name={'eye'} />}  />

Comment: you can use right or left